# jQuery plugin for muti user tweets

Tags: jquery, twitter

Is there any good jQuery plugins for multiple user tweets to be displayed in one module, or is this more of a server side thing using twitters api.  If it's a server side thing where can I find more information about calling different user tweets.

Answer (score 0):

The following library should more or less solve your needs.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-twitter-api/

But if you want to display private status publicly then u have to use oauth implementation . Then I don't think it's a good idea to display private status publicly .That would be a privacy issue .